# Regular Expression for changing chars of the words in string to underscore except First char

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a **regular expression** which modifies the single words in a string containing underscore except the first character.

> **Example**: This is a Test. => T___ i_ a T___.

I'm come up with: **(\w)\w*/g** which results in **T i a T**. But I don't know how to get the underscores in place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
 "This is a Test".replace(/\B\w/g, "_")
```

Explanation: replace every word character, unless it's preceded by a non-word char.

Comment: Ah I was trying to do the same thing but I was using \b instead of \B. Neat solution!

Comment: Works like a charm and is so small. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The naively correct version of your attempt would be

```
var wordMatch = /\b(\w)(\w+)/g;

input.replace(wordMatch, function ($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + (new Array($2.length)).join('_');
});
```

However, this does not work with words that have accented characters, because `\w` only includes the ASCII range (a-z) and it includes the underscore, which strictly speaking is not a word character.

A more correct version would take set of Unicode ranges in place of `\w`:

```
var latinRanges = "\\u0041-\\u005a\\u0061-\\u007a\\u0100-\\u01bf\\u01c4-\\u024f";
    wordMatch = new RegExp("(?:^|[^" + latinRanges + "])([" + latinRanges + "])([" + latinRanges + "]+)", "g");

input.replace(wordMatch, function ($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + (new Array($2.length)).join('_');
});
```

The ranges `\u0041-\u005a`, `\u0061-\u007a`, `\u0100-\u01bf` and `\u01c4-\u024f` include every character in the extended Latin alphabet (basic forms, accented forms, upper- and lowercase forms).

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this,

```
> var s = 'This is a Test.'
> s.replace(/((?:^|\s)\w)(\w*)/g, function(x,y,z) {return y+z.replace(/./g, '_')});
'T___ i_ a T___.'
```

- `((?:^|\s)\w)` regex captures the first word character along with the preceding space or start of the line boundary.
- `(\w*)` captures the following zero or more word characters.
- So the whole match was referred by the first functional parameter `x` then the chars inside the first captured group was referred by `y` and the chars inside second captured group was referred by `z`.
- Now the whole match was replaced by ,

  - `y` -> chars inside first capturing group.
  - Plus
  - `z.replace(/./g, '_')` will replace each char present inside the second capturing group with `_` symbol. Then the final result was concatenated with `y` and forms the final replacement string.

Comment: Works great. But even easier is the solution of georg

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression, as you say mtaches the word. To replace the letters with _ use the replace variant with a function parameter:

```
 var sentence = "Now is the time for all good men";
 var cached = sentence.replace (/(\w)(\w*)/g, 
                 function (_,initial,  rest) { 
                   return initial + rest.replace (/./g, '_'); 
                 });
```